# Why I can't insert data on my database using my webhost?

Tags: php, mysql

There's no error but it is saying that it is `Insert Successfully` but when I check my database there are no fields added to the table `car_category`. This happened when I transfer it to a online webhost.

### insert.php

```
<?PHP
include_once("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['txtCarModel']) && isset($_POST['txtCarType']) && 
isset($_POST['txtCapacity']) && isset($_POST['txtImage'])){
$Car_Model = $_POST['txtCarModel'];
$Car_Type = $_POST['txtCarType'];
$Capacity = $_POST['txtCapacity'];
$Image = $_POST['txtImage'];

$query = "INSERT INTO car_category(Car_Model, Car_Type, Capacity, Image) 
VALUES ('$Car_Model', '$Car_Type', $Capacity, '$Image')"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if($result == 0){
    if(isset($_POST['mobile']) && $_POST['mobile'] == "android"){
        echo "success";
        exit;
    }
    echo "Insert Successfully";   
}
else{
    if(isset($_POST['mobile']) && $_POST['mobile'] == "android"){
        echo "failed";
        exit;
    }
    echo "Something Error";   
}
}

?>
<html>
<head><title>Insert</title></head>
<body>

    <form action="<?PHP $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
        Car Model <input type="text" name="txtCarModel" value=""/><br/>
        Car Type <input type="text" name="txtCarType" value=""/><br/>
        Capacity <input type="text" name="txtCapacity" value=""/><br/>
        Image URL <input type="text" name="txtImage" value=""/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Insert"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'll post my connection.php here in case the problem is in here.

### connection.php

```
<?php
$servername = "*****"; 
$username = "*****"; 
$password = "*****";  
$dbname = "******";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Try to `echo` your `errors`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);// at top of page
// echo $query; die; to see what your query is
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_errpr($conn));
```

**Also your code is `sql Vulnerable` use `mysqli prepared statements` or `PDO`**

**You can try this**

```
 <?PHP
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'databasename');
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);// at top of page

    if(isset($_POST['txtCarModel']) && isset($_POST['txtCarType']) && 
    isset($_POST['txtCapacity']) && isset($_POST['txtImage'])){


    $Car_Model = $_POST['txtCarModel'];
    $Car_Type = $_POST['txtCarType'];
    $Capacity = $_POST['txtCapacity'];
    $Image = $_POST['txtImage'];

           $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO car_category (Car_Model, Car_Type, Capacity, Image) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)");
           $query = "INSERT INTO car_category(Car_Model, Car_Type, Capacity, Image) 
    VALUES ('$Car_Model', '$Car_Type', $Capacity, '$Image')"; 

        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $Car_Model, $Car_Type, $Capacity,$Image);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
    if($result === false ) {
      die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }else{
    echo "New records created successfully";
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

        }

    ?>
```

Comment: Where exactly should I put that `error_reporting(E_ALL);`? On my `connection.php` or `insert.php`?

Comment: you can put it either connection.php or after include_once("connection.php");

Comment: Thank you sir! This helped me alot! You're the best! @mamta

Answer (score 0):

`if($result == 0){`

That means do the following code when mysqli_query() could not execute the query.

The documentation says:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Since you're using an INSERT statement, true or false is expected. Looking at the else code, it might very well be that its the reason why it says "Something Error" you should compare it with `$result === true`

Secondly, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Learn how to [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) statements before [executing](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) them.